# Miniatura imagem pelo Javascript e enviar para Firebase Storage

Tags: upload, firebase

Ae Pessoal, atualmente tenho um serviço de enviar imagem ao Firebase e armazeno a URL da mesma. Até ai tudo bem, porém gostaria de gerar uma miniatura da mesma image e enviar para o firebase também. Para tal, necessitaria gerar a miniatura via Javascript. Poderiam me dar uma Luz?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://medium.com/@rosariopfernandes/firebase-cloud-functions-f6ed3787fa8d) para tal. Eles têm até um [exemplo aqui](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/thumbnails) que usa o ImageMagick para gerar a miniatura:

```
'use strict';

// [START import]
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')();
const spawn = require('child-process-promise').spawn;
const path = require('path');
const os = require('os');
const fs = require('fs');
// [END import]

// [START generateThumbnail]
/**
 * When an image is uploaded in the Storage bucket We generate a thumbnail automatically using
 * ImageMagick.
 */
// [START generateThumbnailTrigger]
exports.generateThumbnail = functions.storage.object().onChange((event) => {
  // [END generateThumbnailTrigger]
  // [START eventAttributes]
  const object = event.data; // The Storage object.

  const fileBucket = object.bucket; // The Storage bucket that contains the file.
  const filePath = object.name; // File path in the bucket.
  const contentType = object.contentType; // File content type.
  const resourceState = object.resourceState; // The resourceState is 'exists' or 'not_exists' (for file/folder deletions).
  const metageneration = object.metageneration; // Number of times metadata has been generated. New objects have a value of 1.
  // [END eventAttributes]

  // [START stopConditions]
  // Exit if this is triggered on a file that is not an image.
  if (!contentType.startsWith('image/')) {
    console.log('This is not an image.');
    return null;
  }

  // Get the file name.
  const fileName = path.basename(filePath);
  // Exit if the image is already a thumbnail.
  if (fileName.startsWith('thumb_')) {
    console.log('Already a Thumbnail.');
    return null;
  }

  // Exit if this is a move or deletion event.
  if (resourceState === 'not_exists') {
    console.log('This is a deletion event.');
    return null;
  }

  // Exit if file exists but is not new and is only being triggered
  // because of a metadata change.
  if (resourceState === 'exists' && metageneration > 1) {
    console.log('This is a metadata change event.');
    return null;
  }
  // [END stopConditions]

  // [START thumbnailGeneration]
  // Download file from bucket.
  const bucket = gcs.bucket(fileBucket);
  const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), fileName);
  const metadata = {
    contentType: contentType,
  };
  return bucket.file(filePath).download({
    destination: tempFilePath,
  }).then(() => {
    console.log('Image downloaded locally to', tempFilePath);
    // Generate a thumbnail using ImageMagick.
    return spawn('convert', [tempFilePath, '-thumbnail', '200x200>', tempFilePath]);
  }).then(() => {
    console.log('Thumbnail created at', tempFilePath);
    // We add a 'thumb_' prefix to thumbnails file name. That's where we'll upload the thumbnail.
    const thumbFileName = `thumb_${fileName}`;
    const thumbFilePath = path.join(path.dirname(filePath), thumbFileName);
    // Uploading the thumbnail.
    return bucket.upload(tempFilePath, {
      destination: thumbFilePath,
      metadata: metadata,
    });
    // Once the thumbnail has been uploaded delete the local file to free up disk space.
  }).then(() => fs.unlinkSync(tempFilePath));
  // [END thumbnailGeneration]
});
// [END generateThumbnail]
```